# How do I download the latest OSS package of nexus using wget

Tags: nexus

I am trying to script the download of the latest OSS nexus package and am unable to find the HTTP address on their site. I wrote to Mark Miller and he redirected me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the URL e.g. from the Docker recipe at https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus/blob/master/oss/Dockerfile